# MySQL query sanity check, for update query

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
update user_remember_me set
when='2012-07-06 05:44:27',
hash='c8e9d2c0dd156b5c68d0b048e5daa948e6b8fac7'
where user = '21';
```

and I am getting this error

> > Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when='2012-07-06 05:44:27', hash='c8e9d2c0dd156b5c68d0b048e5daa948e6b8fac7' wher' at line 1

Im failing to miss the connection here, I've used simple updates like this everywhere without issue til this, maybe Im getting to tired, but this is gonna drive me nuts til I have an answer

Comment: As an aside, you should look into using bcrypt or PBKDF2 for password hashing. SHA1 isn't very secure for this purpose, and it's even less so if you're not salting your hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When is a key word in mysql, change the column name
or you can use it as

```
`when`='2012-07-06 05:44:27'
```

Comment: doh! why, didnt I see that.. sleepy time, quick fix and bed for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`when` is a [reserved word in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

```
update user_remember_me set
`when`='2012-07-06 05:44:27',
`hash`='c8e9d2c0dd156b5c68d0b048e5daa948e6b8fac7'
where user = '21';
```

So you must backtick your column

Answer (score 1):

`when` is a keyword within MySQL. You have to escape it, if you want to use it as a column identifier (as you should with all column identifiers!):

```
UPDATE user_remember_me 
SET
  `when`='2012-07-06 05:44:27',
  `hash`='c8e9d2c0dd156b5c68d0b048e5daa948e6b8fac7'
WHERE `user` = '21';
```